# Structuring the store in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

Is there a way to structure `const reducer = (state = initialState, action)` in such a manner that the method isn't bloated by a bunch of switch cases?

My idea was to put related actions in arrays and check them with `Array.prototype.includes()` when handling an action.

I would then extract the switch cases that correlate to specific actions in new methods (for example the `List` component would have `LIST_ADD`, `LIST_REMOVE` etc.) and call those methods instead of just running through 100 cases in the `const reducer = (state = initialState, action)`method.

That would tax performance but it would be at least structured.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offical Redux [docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/reducing-boilerplate#reducers) provide this very handy reducer creator:

```
function createReducer(initialState, handlers) {
  return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
      return handlers[action.type](state, action)
    } else {
      return state
    }
  }
}
```

which lets you create your reducer as follows:

```
const reducer = createReducer(initialState, {
  [actionType.ACTION1]: specificActionReducer1,
  [actionType.ACTION2]: specificActionReducer2,
}
```

No switch statements!

Answer (score 0):

I use a library called reduxsauce which removes the need for large switch statements.

https://github.com/infinitered/reduxsauce

Instead it binds actions to methods with this syntax:

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
    values: {},
}

export const reducerFunction = (state, action) => {
    const values = action.value;

    return {
        ...state,
        values,
    };
};

// map the action types to the reducer functions
export const HANDLERS = {
    [Type.ACTION_NAME]: reducerFunction,
    ...
}

// call createReducer to magically tie it all together
export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, HANDLERS);
```

Comment: Cool, I will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [redux-named-reducers](https://github.com/mileschristian/redux-named-reducers) for this as well.  Allows you to compose reducers like so:

```
moduleA.reduce(SOME_ACTION, action => ({ state1: action.payload }))
moduleA.reduce(SOME_OTHER_ACTION, { state2: "constant" })
```

It has the added benefit of being able to access the reducer state anywhere, like in mapDispatchToProps for example:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(someAction(getState(moduleA.state1)));
    }
  };
};
```